# how do I get the clipboard to work again after using RDP connections?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, clipboard

I'm using RDP to connect to several other systems on our network. Frequently when doing this the clipboard in the not-remote system will fail to work. For example:

- have some RDP connections open
- open Notepad++
- type text
- select text
- right click on selected text, select Copy
- click elsewhere, right click, select Paste

I expect to see the text that I copied pasted in the document. In reality nothing happens. This seems to only happen while using Remote Desktop. Can I get the clipboard to "come back" somehow?

(the solutions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/254333/clipboard-stopped-working) are a bit too extreme (restart) or didn't work at all)

This blog post is helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2006/11/16/why-does-my-shared-clipboard-not-work-part-1.aspx

Comment: Which version of Remote Desktop are you using on your Windows 7 computer? And have you tried to install the latest update from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592687/ ?

Comment: It tells me that KB2592687 is already installed. The Remote Desktop Connection dialog says it is version 6.3.9600

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found was to kill the clipboard process (rdpclip.exe, I think).